# Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345) next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have problem with typeScript in next.js

Error that i get:

Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)

my code is

```
newpassengerdata?.filter((i:any)=>selectedList.indexOf(i.id)<0)
```

I even try this but result was same

```
interface PassengerData {
    id: number;
  }
...
let newpassengerdata = passdata?.data?.filter((i:any)=>i?.name.includes(inputsearch) || i?.surName.includes(inputsearch))
...
newpassengerdata?.filter((i:PassengerData)=>selectedList.indexOf(i.id)<0)
```

this is newpassengerdata

```
{newpassengerdata?.filter((i:any)=>selectedList.indexOf(i.id)<0)?.slice(pageVisited, pageVisited + postPerPage)?.map((i: any, index: any) => {
                      return (
                        <tbody className={styles1.tbsize} key={index}>
                          <tr className={styles1.tblbody}>
                            <td>{(index + 1)+(pageVisited)}</td>
                            <td>
                              {i?.name}
                              <br />
                              {i?.surName}
                            </td>
                            {i.namePerfix === 1 ? <td>female</td> : <td>male</td>}
                            <td>{i.docId}</td>
                            <td>{i.nationalId}</td>
                            <td>{i.birthDate.split( "T" )[0]}</td>
                            <td>{i.expireDate.split( "T" )[0]}</td>
                            <td>
                              <button type="button" className={styles1.btntable} onClick={()=>{
                    
                    let selectedListt = [...selectedList];
                    // @ts-ignore
                    selectedListt = selectedListt.filter((i)=> values.airTraveler[passengerindex].id !== i);
                              
                    values.passengers[passengerindex].id=i.id;
                    values.passengers[passengerindex].namePerfix=i.namePerfix;
                    values.passengers[passengerindex].nationalId=i.nationalId;
                    values.passengers[passengerindex].name=i.name;
                    values.passengers[passengerindex].surName=i.surName;
                    values.passengers[passengerindex].birthDate=i.birthDate;
                    values.passengers[passengerindex].docId=i.docId;
                    values.passengers[passengerindex].expireDate=i.expireDate;
                    // @ts-ignore
                    selectedListt.push(i?.id);
                    setselectedList(selectedListt);
              handleClose()}}>
                                choose
                              </button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      );
                    })}
```

Comment: Please include `newpassengerdata`

Comment: added to first post

Comment: what is `passdata`? Please make sure that you only provide relevant code so that when we copy and paste the code into our IDEs we will only see the error that you are trying to fix